# Query optimization with extreme statistic

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

I have a table:

```
mysql> describe table_1; 
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(12)          | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| date          | datetime         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| col1          | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 1                   |                |
| col2          | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| col3          | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 1                   |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

with the following characteristics:

```
mysql> select distinct(col1), count(col1) from table_1 group by col1;
+--------+---------------+
| col1   | count(col1)   |
+--------+---------------+
|      0 |           200 |
|      1 |        689747 |
+--------+---------------+
```

How can I optimize queries like these, and with what kind of indexes?

```
1. SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1
AND id NOT IN (79869)  ORDER BY  date  DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
2. SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1 AND id <> 18983
AND date > '2012-10-26'  AND ( col2 LIKE '%word1%' OR  col2 LIKE '%word2%')
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, you have a cardinality problem with `col1`.

Looking at the two queries you posted in the question:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1
AND id NOT IN (79869) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 10;

SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1 AND id <> 18983
AND date > '2012-10-26' AND (col2 LIKE '%word1%' OR col2 LIKE '%word2%')
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

you need good indexes that will accommodate these two queries. In your particular case, you will need just one index.

If the table is MyISAM, here is that index

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD INDEX col1_date_ndx (col1,date,col2,id);
```

If the table is InnoDB, here is that index

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD INDEX col1_date_ndx (col1,date,col2);
```

How will this index help? Although you have to live with the lopsided cardinality of `col1`, you improve each query's chances of being effectively searched.

You could also take a chance on refactoring the queries. How ???

Perhaps you could collect the ids only then join the ids back to the original table.

## QUERY #1

Here is the first query

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1
AND id NOT IN (79869) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Collect the ids and join back to table_1

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1
AND id NOT IN (79869) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 10) A
LEFT JOIN table_1 B USING (id);
```

## QUERY #2

Here is the second query

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1 AND id <> 18983
AND date > '2012-10-26' AND (col2 LIKE '%word1%' OR col2 LIKE '%word2%')
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Collect the ids and join back to table_1

```
SELECT B* FROM
(SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col1 = 1 AND id <> 18983
AND date > '2012-10-26' AND (col2 LIKE '%word1%' OR col2 LIKE '%word2%')
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5) A
LEFT JOIN table_1 B USING (id);
```

I cannot make promises on the queries, but, at the very least, the index suggestion should help.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Is order of columns in your proposed index important for those queries?